# SurveyMonkey: Cannot access Token using OAuth

Tags: php, oauth, surveymonkey

I'm new to OAuth and I need help in accessing the Survey Monkey API to get the auth token. I tried using login_with_surveymonkey.php code and changed the client_id, client_secret, and api_key (https://developer.surveymonkey.com/apps/mykeys). It is giving me this error message:

'it was not possible to open the OAuth access token URL: could not resolve the host domain "api.surveymonkey.net"'

I tried running it on our dev environment and the error returned changed: 'it was not possible to access the OAuth access token: it was returned an unexpected response status 401 Response: {"error_description": "Invalid client_id/client_secret/api_key", "error": "invalid_client"}'

However, when I used the io-docs (https://developer.surveymonkey.com/io-docs) using the same client_id, client_secret, and api_key, I was able to connect to retrieve a token. I have curl working on my local machine.

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like where you're running the code from doesn't have access to the domain.

Comment: I'm running it on local. Does it mean that it doesn't have access to that domain?

Comment: I wonder if the Survey Monkey API needs cURL enabled, have you enabled that plugin in your PHP setup?

Comment: extension=php_curl.dll was already enabled from php.ini but it's still giving me the same error message. Are there other ways to get auth token? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IO Docs API console does not actually perform OAuth correctly and is unfortunately not a good model on how to do OAuth - we have a replacement coming very soon.

The source code for that PHP OAuth implementation looks good, so I would check the following things:

- client_id is your Mashery username
- client_secret is a 32 character long secret associated with the api key you are providing - you can view it here https://developer.surveymonkey.com/apps/mykeys

Edit: According to our logs, it looks like you've solved this problem, correct?  I think you were providing the api_key as the client_secret.

Comment: I already provided the correct client_id, client_secret, redirect_url, and api_key which was provided here https://developer.surveymonkey.com/apps/mykeys but I was still getting this error message

Error: it was not possible to access the OAuth access token: it was returned an unexpected response status 401 Response: {"error_description": "Invalid client_id/client_secret/api_key", "error": "invalid_client"}

Do I need to configure anything else?

Thanks!